# How to move and map objects within a JSON. In Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have an issue, I am trying to move objects within a JSON.

I am currently using Javascript/React and open to using lodash.

This is the following JSON.

```
{
  "data1": [
    { "status": "off", "height": 12 },
    { "status": "on" , "height":  4 }
  ],
  "data2": [
    { "status": "off", "height": 24 },
    { "status": "on" , "height":  4 }
  ],
  "data3": [
    { "status": "off", "height": 12 },
    { "status": "on" , "height":  5 },
    { "status": "off", "height":  5 }
  ],
  "data4": [],
  "data5": [
    { "status": "on" , "height":  5 },
    { "status": "off", "height": 50 },
    { "status": "on" , "height": 50 }
  ]
}
```

**My problem:** Every 'dataX' has to start with a status "on" and end with a status "off", if 'datax' first entry is "status": "off" it needs to be shifted to the JSON array before it. This includes when mapping "data5" it should shift to "data1"

What I am trying to achieve as the end result is therefore, all the value are shifted correctly:

```
{
  "data1": [
    { "status": "on" , "height": 50 },
    { "status": "off", "height": 12 },
    { "status": "on" , "height":  4 },
    { "status": "off", "height": 24 }
  ],
  "data2": [
    { "status": "on" , "height":  4 },
    { "status": "off", "height": 12 }
  ],
  "data3": [
    { "status": "on" , "height":  5 },
    { "status": "off", "height":  5 }
  ],
  "data4": [],
  "data5": [
    { "status": "on" , "height":  5 },
    { "status": "off", "height": 50 }
  ]
}
```

I hope that makes sense?

I have attempted starting to 'map' the JSON object.values and then filter but I have just become stuck.

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT:

This is what I have so far, it finds all instances of the first element containing "off" splices it from the array. Then stores this in another array.

Therefore there are now two arrays, the original (now modified) removed of its first position if it contains "off".

The second array stores these removed items.

My hope is then to shift those items up one array index.

```
const newdb = Object.entries(data);

const original = newdb.map((item) => ({
  name: item[0],
  data: item[1],
}));

const cutout = newdb.map((item) => ({
  name: item[0],
  data:
    item[1][0] && item[1][0].status === "off" ? item[1].splice(0, 1) : [],
}));
```

Comment: What should happen if the very first object (data1) doesn't start with a property with a status of 'on'? In other words, is your use of data# meaningful, or is it just a placeholder so long as the values for each are correct?

Comment: I would store the dataX attributes in an array instead of an object. Then run a Sort function where you return numerical values based on what you expect

Comment: Please show what you have already done as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DaveMeehan I have now added my latest try. :) thanks

Comment: The desired result seems inconsistent. If `data2` starts with "off" the element is placed at the end of `data1`.  If `data3` starts with "off" the element is placed at the end of `data2`. Yet if `data1` starts with "off" it *takes* the last element of `data5`. I would expect the element to be *placed* at the end of `data5`. Not take from it.

Comment: @3limin4t0r it maybe the case, but it was just the data i was given. Any help is appreciated though so thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This answer assumes that the entries have always alternating status.

```js
const dataMap = {
  data1: [
    { status: "off", height: 12 },
    { status: "on", height: 4 },
  ],
  data2: [
    { status: "off", height: 24 },
    { status: "on", height: 4 },
  ],
  data3: [
    { status: "off", height: 12 },
    { status: "on", height: 5 },
    { status: "off", height: 5 },
  ],
  data4: [],
  data5: [
    { status: "on", height: 5 },
    { status: "off", height: 50 },
    { status: "on", height: 50 },
  ],
};

const dataArr = Object.values(dataMap)

dataArr.forEach((item, index) => {
    if (index === 0 || item.length == 0) return
    if (item[0].status === "off") {
        const prevItem = dataArr[index-1]
        const entry = item.splice(0, 1)[0]
        prevItem.push(entry)
    }
    if (index == dataArr.length-1) {
        if (item[item.length-1].status === "on") {
            const entries = [...item.splice(item.length-1, 1), ...dataArr[0]]
            dataArr[0].splice(0, dataArr[0].length, ...entries)  // change the contents of data1 note that data1 still points to the same array after this operation
        }
    }
})

console.log(dataMap)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the reply and great content! I will have a go at this and report back :)